# Can An Event Listener Be Pressed Into Service As a Potential Input, By Assigning A Value, IF, It Gets RUN?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What I am attempting to discover is how to set a value when the function inside
and Event Listener gets executed.  If that can be done, then that value, could be used
to control other potential actions.  Not having found precise material about this, I have
been experimenting.  The below code, doesn't raise any alarms with the Chrome
JS Console, and it does perform the `alert(77)` when the mouse leaves
`MoscowNights` Div, but there is no value on the backend of the whole claptrap
codeblock.

```
function IsolateThaBUG() {
  var MoscowNights = document.getElementById("MoscowNights");

  MoscowNights.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
    var MaloMaloJavaScript = 77;
    alert(MaloMaloJavaScript);
    return MaloMaloJavaScript;
  }, false);

  var Convoluted = MoscowNights;
  return Convoluted;
}

var GotAnythingYET = IsolateThaBUG();
alert('Got This NONSENSE Instead : ' + GotAnythingYET);
```

---

Right, well... this next block also does not give up a value... or so it would seem.  If it was accessible, it should be showing up in the div, but it reads *undefined* so... maybe there is no way to do this in one go.

```
    function IsolateThaBUG(){
       var MoscowNights = document.getElementById('MoscowNights');
        var MaloMaloJavaScript; // temp undefnd
        MoscowNights.addEventListener("mouseout", function (evt) {
            var MaloMaloJavaScript=77;   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<    THAT,
            }, false);
        return MaloMaloJavaScript;   >>>>>>>>>>>>    is just NOT getting OUTSIDE!!
    }
     var GotAnythingYET = IsolateThaBUG();
     function WritetestValue() {
        var artfulArtificial = document.getElementById("whattheSAMHILLsigoinon");
        var TitleWrite = artfulArtificial.appendChild(document.createTextNode(testValue));
        return TitleWrite;
    }
    WritetestValue();
```

The answer I accepted, does the job as I discovered when I studied it, got it installed and tested it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a work around for addEventListener callbacks with return value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592282/is-there-a-work-around-for-addeventlistener-callbacks-with-return-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you wrote `IsolateThaBug` is returning the value of `MoscowNights`, which is an element.

I'm surmising that you wish to retrieve the value of `MaloMaloJavascript`. In order to accomplish this, you need to pass in a callback or some other variable with which to mutate.

Here are a few examples.

```
function testMouseout() {
  var element = document.getElementById('MoscowNights'); 
  var testValue;  // undefined currently.
  element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    testValue = 77;
  }, false);
  return testValue;
}

var mouseoutTest = testMouseout(); 
console.log(mouseoutTest); // undefined
// perform the mouseout action. If you did, the value will be 77.
window.setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(mouseoutTest) // 77
}, 5000)
```

If you want to wait till fire the alert until the mouseout has happened, you can pass in a callback function. This takes advantage of JavaScript's first-class functions.

```
function testMouseout(callback) {
  var element = document.getElementById('MoscowNights'); 
  var testValue;  // undefined currently.
  element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    testValue = 77;
    callback(testValue);
  }, false);
  return testValue;
}

// we pass in a function that will 
// be executed when the event fires.
testMouseout(function(value) {
  alert(value); // 77
});
```

Comment: Wow, that is a lot to absorb, thanks a bunch! I'll get back to you as soon as I can put it in my script and discover what is all does.  Yes, I get [object HTMLelementdiv] or somesuch, in the alert whereas as you deduced, it is that *77* I am after.

Comment: Yeah, basically you just have to remember that when you're working with events, you're working asynchronously - so you can't rely on assignment. Much easier to pass around functions which have references to what you want. Well, not easy - but more sane.