# I keep getting a returned value of "undefined" in the console, but have clearly returned my value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, undefined

I keep getting undefined for my value when I put it through console.log, but I'm returning a value each time. Why is it doing this? I have my var defined, and It should work, but I just keep getting undefined regardless. Please help.

```
Size_Price = 0;
document.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // check it's an element we're interested in
    if (event.target.classList.contains('pizza')) {
        if (document.getElementById("small") == event.target) {
            document.getElementById("Choice1").textContent = "Small";
            return Size_Price + 5
        } else if (document.getElementById("medium") == event.target) {
            document.getElementById("Choice1").textContent = "Medium";
            return Size_Price + 10
        } else if (document.getElementById("large") == event.target) {
            document.getElementById("Choice1").textContent = "Large";
            return Size_Price + 15
        } else {
            document.getElementById("Choice1").textContent = "Fatso"
            return Size_Price + 18
        }}
```

Comment: Change the `Size_Price` directly without ***returning it***. It will work for you. Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a work around for addEventListener callbacks with return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592282/is-there-a-work-around-for-addeventlistener-callbacks-with-return-value)

Answer (score 1):

So when you use the return keyword inside an event listener function, it doesn't actually return the value back to where the event listener was originally called from. It just exits the event listener function itself - the value doesn't get passed anywhere. That's why you're seeing undefined when you try to log it, because nothing is being returned to that console.log statement. The return value just gets lost inside the event listener function.